# Changing the value of an ActiveX control field in Word through a VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to write a Word VBA Macro that automatically fills in ActiveX control fields in a Word document using data contained in an Excel file. I managed to open and retrieve values from the Excel file, but I am getting stuck on changing the values of the ActiveX control fields.

**How can the value of ActiveX control fields be accessed and modified in VBA ?**

By "field", I means both text fields, radio buttons and check boxes (e.g. checking/unchecking the box in the VBA Macro).

A link to a page with a clear explanation of how to work with ActiveX control fields in VBA is also welcome, as I haven't been able to find any useful material so far (on this particular point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exemple you can do  :

For Label

`UserFormName.LabelName.Caption = "Test"` 'Label's text will be Test

For CheckBox

```
UserFormName.CheckBoxName.Value = True 'CheckBox Checked
```

For TextBox

```
UserFormName.TextBoxName.Value = "Some Text" 'Text in TextBox will be Some Text
```

For Radio Button

```
UserFormName.RadioButtonName.Value = True ' Radio Button activated
```

Is it what you asked for (Not Sure that I understood your needs so please leave **Feedbacks** so I can improve this answer) ?

**Edit :**

To get the name :

1. Select the item
2. read the name in the property window

For exemple  :
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I need. However, where can I find the `UserFormName` for my document ?

Comment: @johnwolf1987 Please see my edit, **Note** That you can change the name if ou want (Just click on the name and type what you want)

Comment: Ok, thanks. It works now! I didn't actually have a "UserForm" as I inserted the objects directly on the Word page. So i had to write `ThisDocument.TextBox1.Value = "Text"`

Comment: @johnwolf1987 yes you got it ;) Glad that I could help you

Answer (score 0):

While ActiveX controls on the document surface can be accessed via the `ThisDocument` class module, this only works with controls *in that document*.

If the code should work with controls in other documents, or documents created from a template, then a different approach is required.

The following code sample can be in any code module. It accesses the ActiveX controls in any document via their "OLE interface".

The control can be either an `InlineShape` (in-line with the text) or a `Shape` (text-wrap formatting) - just use the appropriate collection. `OLEFormat.Object` picks up the control, itself.

```
Sub WriteToActiveX()
    Dim ils As Word.InlineShape
    Dim olef As Word.OleFormat
    Dim tb As MSForms.TextBox

    Set ils = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
    Set olef = ils.OleFormat
    Set tb = olef.Object
    tb.Text = "Test"
End Sub
```